# VSCode Python debugger stopped launching

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode v1.69.0. My OS is MacOS v10.15.7 (Catalina).

I have a Python code that I'm usually debugging with VSCode Python debugger (using the launch.json file).

For no apparent reason the debugger recently stopped working, i.e. when I click on "Run Debug", the debug icons (stop, resume, step over etc.) show up for 1 second, then disappear and nothing else happens. There is no error message in the terminal or anything (no command is launched apparently).

I tried to uninstall VSCode and reinstall it => no success.
I deleted the Python extension in /*userprofile*/.vscode/extensions and then reinstalled it (both the current v2022.10.1 and pre-release v2022.11.12011103) => no success.

The python program runs properly on another IDE.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `python3.6` version then latest version of debugger no longer supports it.

You can use the historical version `2022.08.*`. Or use a new python version.

Comment: Is it possible to support jupyter notebook feature as well for latest VSCode + Python extension 2022.08.*? I'm stuck to using python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04, but I cannot find a jupyter extension version that can successfully select kernel in latest VSCode (v1.82.2).

Comment: Hello, how to select debugger version?